# Creating a Border for Only 2 Rows HTML

Tags: html, border, cell

I'm trying to multiplication table in html, but it requires only a border below the top row and to the right of the left row.  Everything within the table will not be separated by borders.  However, I feel stumped because I think you cannot do this, is it even possible to only add a border to one cell?

edit: dear freinds i have discovered an image from the internet that demonstrates what I am trying to achieve.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/y364h.jpg For my table, is it possible to only have borders corresponding to the bold border from the image within my html table?

Comment: are you talking about _right of the left row_ or **right of the left column**. Provide a sample of what you want to achieve, some sample pic or code.

Comment: I have applied a picture to stackoverflow

Comment: Please post the code you did, even if it doesn't work. Without code we cannot help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with CSS. Here is a sample I am providing

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Border-Test</title>

        <style>
            .border-side {
                border-right: 1px solid black;
            }

            .border-bottom td { 
                border-bottom: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr><td colspan="5">Addition</td></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="border-bottom">
                    <td class="border-side"> </td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="border-side">0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="border-side">1</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="border-side">2</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="border-side">3</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the output of above

[image]

**NOTE** : You need to change the table cell data which I haven't changed.
**NOTE** : You also must need to specify the `cellspacing="0"`.

Comment: You can remove the attribute and try through css.